# Adding Administrators Via Group Policy

Tags: windows, dns

My Windows Vista work computer is a member of a domain.  The domain administrators have set up a group policy that keeps adding them as Administrators of my computer every night.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?  I am an Administrator on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

These are serious answers:

- disconnect your PC from the network
- remove your PC from the domain

You can't change group policy: it can override local settings or not be overridden.
Domain admins trump local admins in AD

But why?

Comment: Disconnecting won't help as group policies are cached locally, and removing it from the domain require domain admin privileges anyway... but yeah, that's it - but he'd need the admins cooperation ^^

Comment: he he. I did not know that (it's been a while since I was a sysadmin)

Comment: @OskarDuveborn Removing it from the domain only requires local admin privileges. The applet also tries to disable the computer account in Active Directory, but the removal does not fail if it cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no (useful) way. This isn't however a technical problem at all but a policy problem (if a problem at all). Take it up with your administrators and your boss. Ask them why and they should explain.

This behaviour is a default policy by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  There are a number of ways at your disposal.  A few ideas:

- Delete their local admin. Add your own local admin user with the same username but a different password.  The GPO addition will assume the user is already there and not make any changes.
- Update registry permissions to remove access to any of the several keys required to add a user.  Mark Russinovich describes procedures [on his blog](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2005/04/30/circumventing-group-policy-settings.aspx).
- Edit the NTFS permissions on the directory where the group policy objects are cached.  (this, of course, will break *all* GPOs, not just the local admin...)

*bottom line*: as a local admin, you can do *anything*.  In order for Group Policy to work and for the GPO to add a local user, it must do *something*.  Break any part of that something and you've found your solution.

Of course, just because you *can*, but that doesn't mean you *should*.  I was an IT guy, users did this to me, and it's irritating.  It's a policy issue and should be handled via non-technical means.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you connect to your work network this will happen, it's how companies control their computers, I recommend talking to a network administrator.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Regedit.exe.
- Browse to the following path - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MMC\`
- Expand the unique key contained within
- Set `Restrict_Run` to the value 1 (done by double clicking to edit and typing 1)

http://www.computerstepbystep.com/group_policy_windows_7.html